# how to add drop down list in material-UI Search component in navbar, for search results

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I was using material ui search bar into navbar from [app-bar-with-search-field official documnets from MUI](https://mui.com/pt/material-ui/react-app-bar/#app-bar-with-search-field) in my react app. but this article it does not mention how to add dropdown list on selecting search input field.

I was tried many ways including **Menu**, **List** components from MUI for implement drop menu but didn't work for me. please help me to figure it out how i can add dropdown list of width of serach bar for showing a search results.
[codesendbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-voice-f0g1yy?file=/src/App.js)

code in my `App.js`

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";
import { styled, alpha } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

const Search = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "relative",
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.black, 0.15),
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.black, 0.25)
  },
  marginTop: "5px",
  marginLeft: 0,
  width: "100%",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "auto"
  }
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center"
}));
const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "red",
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch"
      }
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      width: "0ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "12ch"
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <nav
          id="navbar"
          className=" pt-0 pb-0 ps-3 container-row navbar-dark navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-div fixed-top"
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="navbar-brand">
              <h1 className="logo-text mt-1 text-dark">project logo</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="nav-list">
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      textAlign: "center"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Search>
                      <SearchIconWrapper>
                        <SearchIcon />
                      </SearchIconWrapper>
                      <StyledInputBase
                        placeholder="Search Organization ..."
                        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
                      />
                    </Search>
                  </Box>
                </React.Fragment>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Maybe what you need is [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/pt/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) ?

Comment: @Hoxtygen i tried  Autocomplete too, but i messed up somthing it didn't work, can you please add demonstration in [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-voice-f0g1yy?file=/src/App.js) , i have to fatch data by API call based on input value of search box. 
It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like suggestion from @rupesh patil, you should change to `Autocomplete`, or you also can make `List` show under Search input when your input search `is focused` and catch `keyup` event to search for result manually.

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";
import { styled, alpha } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'];
const Search = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "relative",
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.black, 0.15),
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.black, 0.25)
  },
  marginTop: "5px",
  marginLeft: 0,
  width: "100%",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "auto"
  }
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center"
}));
const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "red",
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch"
      }
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      width: "0ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "12ch"
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <nav
          id="navbar"
          className=" pt-0 pb-0 ps-3 container-row navbar-dark navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-div fixed-top"
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="navbar-brand">
              <h1 className="logo-text mt-1 text-dark">project logo</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="nav-list">
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      textAlign: "center"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Search>
                      <SearchIconWrapper>
                        <SearchIcon />
                      </SearchIconWrapper>
                      {/* <StyledInputBase
                        placeholder="Search Organization ..."
                        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
                      /> */}
                       <Autocomplete
                        value={value}
                        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                          setValue(newValue);
                        }}
                        inputValue={inputValue}
                        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                          setInputValue(newInputValue);
                        }}
                        id="controllable-states-demo"
                        options={options}
                        sx={{ width: 300 }}
                        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search Organization ..." />}
                      />
                    </Search>
                  </Box>
                </React.Fragment>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```